# What are the rules in JS on a variable referencing the same data across a loop?

Tags: javascript, partial-application

I just needed to use partial application to pass data into a callback, and I found I needed a layer of indirection to prevent subsequent runs of a loop from changing the data I'm passing to the callback.

See here for a very simple working example: http://jsfiddle.net/s5gVj/

(if the jsfiddle is self explanatory, feel free to skip straight to the question below)

### Without the indirection

This will always set the label to "Button 1 pressed."

This happens regardless of which button was pressed.

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++)
{
    var buttonID = i;
    $(buttons[i]).click(   
        function(e)
        {
            $("label").html("Button " + buttonID + " pressed.");
        });
}
```

### Indirectly, via a function

Meanwhile, using a function in the middle corrects the problem

For the first button, the result will be "Button 0 pressed"

For the second button, it will be "Button 1 pressed".

```
var buttonClickHandlerWithID = 
    function(buttonID)
    {
        return function(e)
        {
            $("label").html("Button " + buttonID + " pressed.");
        }
    }

for(var i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++)
{
    $(buttons[i]).click(buttonClickHandlerWithID(i));
}
```

Why does this happen? Is there something special about function calls that ensure the variable is copied and thus no longer a reference to the same data, or is there something else going on?

I expected a variable declared within the for loop to be recreated on each iteration, thus each iteration being separate, but I guess that isn't the case?

Comment: instead of adding `buttons.length - 1` number of `click` events - you might wanna consider a delegation, i.e. add a single click event to the parent container and filter targets by button class...

Comment: @tborychowski The buttons in question are generated by jQueryUI, and I don't really want to fiddle with them in a breakable way (they are in the button list it can create for a dialog). So they share the same classes, i could detect their position, but I find this preferable.

Comment: @Bergi quite right, it would have answered my question, thanks. Though the answers here require less prior knowledge, I think. (I'd forgotten about function/block scope, which might have made it harder to interpret the answers there).

Comment: @tborychowski though maybe sharing the click event is possible whilst storing state seperately? I'll investigate. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript only has function scope. All `var` declarations anywhere in a function (well except inside a nested function of course) are treated as if they appeared at the top of the function. Nested `{ ... }` blocks do not have their own scope, which is a significant difference from C++ and Java etc.

Comment: And an annoying one.  Roll on the `let` keyword.

Comment: Yes having `let` is going to be nice.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Feel like I should have known that.

Answer (score 1):

Like Pointy answered, there is only function scope in javascript, meaning `i` in your code is scoped outside the loop, and when referenced later (on click) will be whatever it ended up being after the `for` loop is finished.

If you use jquery's `.each()` instead of `for`, you get local scope because it takes a function as callback.

```javascript
var i = 0;
var directButtons = $("button.direct");

// jquerys each method takes a function callback
directButtons.each(function () {
    i++;
    // since this is inside a function
    var buttonID = i; // buttonID will be locally scoped

    $(this).click(function (e) {
        // this inner function "close over" (google "javascript closure") and
        // remembers the value of buttonID in the .each() loop
        $("label").html("Button " + buttonID + " pressed. " +
          "'i' will be whatever it ended up after the .each() is finished: " + i);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5gVj/3/

Also check out slide 55 of [fixingthesejquery.com](http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide55)

---

You can also solve this using an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (see the part titled "Saving state with closures"):

```
var directButtons = $("button.direct");

for(var i = 0 ; i < directButtons.length ; i++){
    (function(buttonID){
        // buttonID is now scoped to this function
        $(directButtons[buttonID]).click(function (e) {
            $("label.direct").html("Button " + buttonID + " pressed. , 'i' is always " + i);
        });
    })(i); // call the function immediately, supply the value of "i" as parameter
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5gVj/4/